# Visual Studio Errors BC30451

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using VS Community 2015 and I am getting a ton of these on some of the pages in the error list in my project.  They are not valid errors.  If I open the particular page in the source window, they are no longer reported.  I can compile and run the project.  It can make it very difficult to find real errors.

I can not find any info about this error when it is incorrectly reported.

```
Error   BC30451 'GridView1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.    WebSite1(1) C:\...\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite1\EditProjects.aspx.vb  15
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [variable-is-not-declared-it-may-be-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239115/variable-is-not-declared-it-may-be-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level)

Comment: Possible, but that thread had no resolution and the last post date was Dec 2014, and that post and the posts linked in it are actual errors.  The problem I have is that they are **NOT** valid errors.